# Organizar código Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con **Laravel** y tengo una página con dos pestañas. Cada pestaña tiene un formulario distinto(con datos de otros sitios) pero graban en la misma tabla.

He creado el formulario y la primera pestaña con sus controles de **javascript** para rellenar las listas y controlar el flujo de datos,... he creado un archivo .js donde he metido todas las funciones que necesitaba y todo funciona perfectamente.

El caso es que ahora tengo que empezar con la segunda pestaña, con sus elementos con distinto id, distintas llamadas a AJAX, listas y control del flujo de datos.

He optado por la opción de crear distintos ficheros .js para mantener el código mas claro.

¿existe algún problema por declarar distintos $(document).ready en cada fichero?

Comment: @Teteitor, la primera pregunta está basada en opiniones, hay frameworks y módulos para el servidor web que te facilitan la tarea, pero la respuesta es amplia y depende del caso específico. La segunda pregunta sí que tiene respuesta objetiva, pero deberías plantear una única pregunta y no dos, para que el cierre por culpa de la primera no quite la oportunidad de dar respuesta a la segunda. Por favor, formula una nueva pregunta con el punto dos y edita esta pregunta para borrarla de ésta.

Comment: Siento haber formulado una pregunta basada en opiniones, he intentado buscar varias guias de buenas prácticas de Laravel y Javasript pero no explican claramente. Creí que habría algo sobre este tema y esta pregunta sobre todo viene por la experiencia de entrar en otros proyectos con otros lenguajes  y tener que modificar código que no es tuyo, echarte las manos a la cabeza y maldecir al que lo hizo porque es un caos. @Joacer gracias y perdón por tener que editar la pregunta, tengo un teclado inglés y me desespera tener que usar Alt cada vez que quiera poner un acento.

Comment: yo te diria que revisaras tu codigo y, como dice @Teteitor, separar las cosas que sean comunes. Ya que mencionas que van a guardar en la misma tabla, pero van a ser cosas distintas, es posible que la consulta y los parametros sean parecidos. Por tanto, tus llamadas ajax podrian ser parametrizadas y luego en cada formulario, llamar a una misma función con los parametros de cada formulario, o un evento click que capture los datos que necesitas y los lleve al ajax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**¿Debería meter todo el código Javascript en el mismo archivo?**

Si todo el código que vas a incluir se va a usar en todas las páginas entonces la respuesta sería que sí, pero no afectaría gravemente al rendimiento si lo divides en varios archivos.

Por el contrario, si vas a tener un 20% de código común que se va a ejecutar en todas las páginas y el 80% restante se ejecuta únicamente en determinadas secciones, podrías plantearte separar el código común del específico para minimizar la huella de memoria y proceso que estás consumiendo sin darle uso, pero igualmente el impacto no afectaría gravemente al rendimiento.

Hay frameworks que gestionan y facilitan esta tarea, pero no hay regla estricta al respecto, cada programador estructura su código como mejor vea.

*Generalmente esta respuesta está basada en opiniones y dependen de cada caso en particular.*

**En caso de usar distintos archivos `.js` para tenerlo más claro y organizado, ¿no hay problema si en ambos hay un 'document.ready'?**

Supongo que te refieres a un [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) porque `document` no tiene ningún evento llamado `ready`. Quizá te refieras al evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) que puedes usar con [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) o a [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

A continuación te detallo en cada caso si existe o no problema con multitud de llamadas desde diferentes scripts:

- [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/): No hay problema, las llamadas a las funciones registradas se encadenan.
- [`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded): No hay problema, las llamadas a las funciones registradas se encadenan.
- [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload): Hay problema, sólo la última función registrada será la que será llamada.

Por último cabe resaltar que si haces uso de los atributos [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) o [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) ([sólo en los navegadores que lo soportan](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility)) o si cargas los scripts al final del documento HTML podrías evitarte su uso.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado muchísimo.

Comment: Mi intención es crear distintos archivos .js para, a primera, vista saber que te puedes encontrar en cada uno, o si algo falla ir directamente al fichero donde están las funciones de control de la página en concreto. A la hora de cargar los scripts, como bien has dicho, las funciones se encadenarán. Los scripts los tengo que cargar al final de la cabecera para que todo funcione correctamente.

Comment: Hola @Jakala, supongo que te has confundido y has comentado mi respuesta en vez de su pregunta :) Si ha sido una confusión te animo a borrar el mensaje de mi respuesta y volver a publicarlo en su pregunta ;)